# Creating Molecular Orbital and Walsh Diagrams

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, symmetry

Does anyone know of a good website to create your own MO and Walsh diagrams? Could you potentially make them on a software package such as excel?

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) to draw MO diagram by hand.